# Order of Overloaded Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two instances where I am overloading the << operator and it is always defaulting to the first one displayed below is there any way I can get the second function recognized for the custom class Shape?

Thank you,

John

First Overload:

```
    template <class T>
    ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector <T> & vec)
    {
      for (unsigned int i = 0;i<vec.size()-1; i++) {
        out << vec[i] << " ";
      }
      out << vec[vec.size() - 1];

      return out;
    }
```

Second Overload:

```
    ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector <Shape> & vec)
    {
      for (unsigned int i = 0;i<vec.size(); i++)
      {
        out << "##" << vec[i].get_shape_type << i << endl << vec[i] << endl;
      }
      return out;
    }
```

Edit 7/25/2012:

I added put in the same file

```
    #ifndef _UTILS_H_
    #define _UTILS_H_
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include "Shape.H"

    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector <T> & vec)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0;i<vec.size()-1; i++) {
            out << vec[i] << " ";
        }
        out << vec[vec.size() - 1];

        return out;
    }

    template <class Shape>
    ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector <Shape> & vec)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0;i<vec.size(); i++)
        {
            out << "## " <<vec[i];
        }
        return out;
    }
    #endif
```

and tried to compile and I got this error

../include/utils.H:22:11: error: redefinition of ‘template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector&)’
../include/utils.H:11:11: error: ‘template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector&)’ previously declared here

Comment: [Template specialization](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&biw=1920&bih=947&noj=1&gbv=2&sclient=psy-ab&q=template+specialization&oq=template+specialization&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.10010.12203.0.12507.8.6.0.2.2.0.120.460.5j1.6.0...0.0.SsvzcUdFvpA).

Comment: If you comment out the template version, does it compile at all? I suspect only the template version is visible at the call point.

Comment: That should work, as long as the second overload is declared before you use it. Could you post a compilable program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MarkB: It does not compile if "First Overload" is commented out.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: The program is made up of a dozen linked .cpp and custom .H files because their are so many custom classes in this program. The "First Overload" and "Second Overload" are in different files.

Answer (score 1):

Your two functions have identical name and signatures.  Only template parameter names (T, SHAPE) are different. This why compiler complains that you are redefining the same function.  You need to make signature different or add `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the specialization syntax in your edit is wrong. To properly perform the template specialization, instead of this:

```
template <class Shape>
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector <Shape> & vec)
```

you need:

```
template <>
ostream & operator << <Shape> (ostream & out, vector <Shape> & vec)
```

See [this ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on template specialization. However, an alternative solution is to modify your `Shape::operator<<()` to include all the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'overloads' are basically the same function with differently named template parameters, hence redeclaration error. You have to make them actual overloads. The `Shape` version needs not be a template, just a function. Also you probably want to pass vector by const reference:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, vector<Shape> const& vec)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        out << "## " <<vec[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```